# Firebase CLI - How to Manage Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Using the firebase-cli you can easily deploy functions and show the logs. But I have yet to find the option to download or retrieve cloud functions.

I've dug through quiet a bit of the -h commands and nothing yet.

Is it possible to download / retrieve a projects cloud functions through the **firebase-cli**? I tend to switch between computers from home to work and I need to go to the console to copy the source code and redeploy.

Comment: Here is the link to the cli commands I know of.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#functions-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase CLI doesn't provide a way to get deployed code.  It's expected that you use some form of source control for managing code between developers and machines.

Comment: I figured this would be the answer. I will just mark you as the answer in 10 minutes.